# Use Bottom navigation with nav controller

Tags: kotlin

I am using navController with BottomNavigationView. The issue is that when transitioning between fragments with BottomNavigationView, the fragments are being reloaded, causing performance issues. How can I resolve this?

I tried using fragmentTransaction.replace() instead of NavController, and the issue was resolved, but I want to use NavController. Is there no other solution? Please help me.